# passing array to function

Tags: php

Hello everyone please help me out regarding this this piece of code

```
$user = new User();
$user->connect();
$pno=$_POST['pno'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$result = array('name'=>$name,'age'=>$age,'pno'=>$pno);
$error=$user->edit($result);
$user->disconnect();
```

I want to coustomize these line of code

```
$pno=$_POST['pno'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$result = array('name'=>$name,'age'=>$age,'pno'=>$pno);
```

I mean like this

```
$result = array('$_POST['name']'=>$name,'$_POST['age']'=>$age,'$_POST['pno']'=>$pno);
```

but i am unable to put '' properly please help me out regarding this and a small simple hints about qoutes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = array($_POST['name']=>$name,$_POST['age']=>$age,$_POST['pno']=>$pno);
```

The reason why your code was failing was because you are trying to interpolate $_POST['name'] in a string with single quotes, which will fail because $_POST['name'] also contains single quotes(this will raise a Parse error).

Answer (score 0):

You're breaking up the string with the nested quotes. Use "..." in stead, like this:

```
$result = array('$_POST["name"]'=>$name, '$_POST["age"]'=>$age,'$_POST["pno"]'=>$pno);
```

That said, personally I'd go for more descriptive and less cluttered field names, like "name", "age", etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array(
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'age' => $_POST['age'],
    'pno' => $_POST['pno']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array($_POST['name']=>$name, $_POST['age']=>$age, $_POST['pno']=>$pno);
```

That should be work however your array key index will be mixed with number and string, plus your code doesn't work because you use " **'** " witch will interpret $_POST['age'] as a string if it work, double quote can understand variable inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the whole variable name as the key for each of the results variable you could but why?

```
$results['$_POST["name"]'] = $name;
$results['$_POST["age"]'] = $age;
$results['$_POST["pno"]'] = $pno;
```